# Developing plugins for logstash >= v1.5.0

Tags: logstash

Logstash has introduced a new plugin-mechanism with v1.5.0, where the plugins are fetched from rubygems. 
For development what would be the proper way, running/debugging my own plugin without posting to rubygems for every change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got helped from first hand:

[logstash issue #2265](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/2265)